# Why doesn't Spring MVC throw an error when you POST to a controller action that accepts HTTP GET?

Tags: spring, debugging, http, post, spring-mvc

I just noticed a weird problem as I've been testing my application. I was accidentally POSTing to a method that accepts HTTP GET (It was a typo - I'm a little tired), but the weird thing is that Spring was executing a GET action anyway - it wasn't throwing an error.

Here is the mapping for my GET action that I was POSTing to instead:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/partialMapping/{partialMappingId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView edit(@PathVariable long partialMappingId) {
    return new ModelAndView(view("edit"), "partialMapping",
        partialMappingService.findPartialMapping(partialMappingId));
}
```

What I would have expected was for Spring to say, "There is no action called /partialMapping/{partialMappingId}/edit for HTTP POST".

Instead... if you use the `HandlerAdapter` and pass it "POST" and "/partialMapping/1/edit", it runs my `index` action instead ("/partialMapping"). It doesn't throw an error. Why?

Is this a bug in spring, or is this desired behaviour? It's not a big deal when it comes to production code, but it surely makes debugging problems harder.

Here is the code I am using to execute a controller action in my tests:

```
protected ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        final HandlerMapping handlerMapping = applicationContext.getBean(HandlerMapping.class);
        final HandlerExecutionChain handler = handlerMapping.getHandler(request);
        assertNotNull("No handler found for request, check you request mapping", handler);

        final Object controller = handler.getHandler();
        // if you want to override any injected attributes do it here

        final HandlerInterceptor[] interceptors =
            handlerMapping.getHandler(request).getInterceptors();
        for (HandlerInterceptor interceptor : interceptors) {
            final boolean carryOn = interceptor.preHandle(request, response, controller);
            if (!carryOn) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I found this code per another answer to a question on this site.

Comment: Spring *does* throw an error in this case.  Either you really were sending a GET, or Spring wasn't using the config you think it was.

Comment: Well, it doesn't for me when I go through HandlerMapping, HandlerAdapter, etc. I will post this code.

Comment: Don't you think a bug in your test code is more likely than a bug in Spring?  You're mimicing Spring here, and you've missed something.

Comment: @skaffman: Yes, probably your right. I was assuming that the handler would return null in this instance, but it doesn't :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your test code mimics the dispatch step that tries to find a matching `Controller` method signature *after* the URL and HTTP method have resolved. In other words, you are not testing your controller at the right level if you want to test the HTTP message bindings. For that kind of testing you would probably want to deploy to a server (perhaps embedded Jetty inside your test) and use `RestTemplate` to call it. That's what I do anyway.

Comment: Oh really? Okay, I'm just going to keep doing it my way then because I don't want to deal with starting the server to test these. I was hoping that spring would return null for the `handler` variable in this case, but I guess it doesn't. Thank you for this.

Comment: Since Spring 3.2 there is a Spring MVC test framework that can test the MVC code at a high level, including all the request mappings, without the need for a servlet container.

Answer (score -1):

If you annotate with Spring MVC annotations as below
`@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET` it should work.